# Are optional "call-back" parameters in Clojurescript frowned upon?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When you write higher-order functions in Clojurescript, it is actually possible to omit parameters for a passed-in function.

For instance, the following is legal Clojurescript code but illegal Clojure code:

> (def x (atom 5))
>
> (swap! x (fn [] 6))

The higher-order "swap!" function expects a function that takes one parameter, but you can omit it and the program will still compile/run just fine.

Would it be considered bad form to use this ability if it makes my Clojurescript code cleaner? Or, is it just abuse of a Clojurescript limitation? Any opinions?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I posted an answer, but I'm not sure that it's what you're asking about.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but for this particular case, you should use `reset!` instead of `swap!`. It does what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me `(fn [_] 6)` looks very idiomatic and not any more obscure than `(fn [] 6)`. It's even more expressive because it explicitly states that the argument is ignored.

Another advantage of writing the complete (correct) form is portability of your code.

---

EDIT: By the way your example can be rewritten using constantly: `(swap! x (constantly 6))`. `constantly` creates a function that accepts any number of arguments and always returns argument passed to `constantly`.